# AttributeError: '<invalid type>' object has no attribute 'exit'

Tags: python-2.7, importerror, attr

Throws error: `Line 2: AttributeError: '<invalid type>' object has no attribute 'exit'` when `from sys import exit` is run. How do I fix this? Problem part of code:

```
from sys import exit
```

Comment: Does the error message literally say `'<invalid type>'`?

Comment: If code you included starts with line 2, what was in line 1?

Comment: dying to see what was in line 1

Comment: @EoinS: `open("sys.py", 'w').close()` perhaps? :$

Comment: comment1 = yes comment2 = nothing.It was blank. comment3 = It was blank. comment4 = I don't have a local file for sys, i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you happen to create a module or file called `sys`?  If so you are importing from your local module rather than from the built-in Python `sys` module

Otherwise, these import commands are case sensitive, make sure everything is in lower case (it is in your post, but you never know):

```
from sys import exit
```